# R: Count appereances of vector y in x

Tags: r, vector, pattern-matching, counting

Suppose you have two vectors `y` and `x` with `length(y) < length(x)`.
What I want is to count how often all elements of `y` appear in `x` in the same order.
**I can assume that the elements of `y` appear at least one time in `x` in the right order.**

Example:

```
y = c(10,20)
x = c(10,20,20,10,20)
```

The indexpairs of appereances of y in x are:

```
(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(4,5)
```

so my result should be 4.

I've already written a function:

```
countAllPositionsOfLCS <- function(y, x) {
  potIndexList <- lapply(y, function(k) {
     which(k == x)
  })

  previousIndices <- potIndexList[[1]]
  counter <- length(potIndexList[[1]])

  if (length(potIndexList) >= 2) {
    for (k in 2:length(potIndexList)) {
      newIndices <- potIndexList[[k]]
      for (i in 1:length(previousIndices)) {
        currentFittingInds <- newIndices[which(previousIndices[i] < newIndices)]
        counter <- counter + length(currentFittingInds) - 1
      }
      previousIndices <- newIndices
    }  
  }
  counter
}
```

I tested this function with

```
c(10,20,30) and c(10,20,20,10,20,20,30,30)
```

The proper result should be 12, but the function says 10.

Indexpairs are `1,2,7 | 1,2,8 | 1,3,7 | 1,3,8 | 1,5,7 | 1,5,8 | 1,6,7 | 1,6,8 | 4,5,7 | 4,5,8 | 4,6,7 | 4,6,8`.

My idea was following:

First of all I look where the values of y appear in x and for each value of y I store the indices in the list `potIndexList`. 
then I go through all elements of this list, say we are at element `potIndexList[[k]]`, so we have all the indices there, where the k-th element of y apperas in x. Since I want to preserve the order of y in x, I have to get rid of some indices. Therefore I go through the indices and check if `previousIndices[i] < potIndexList[[k]]`. If this is `TRUE` I know that the order is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `expand.grid` unless your actual problem involves much larger vectors:

```
y  = c(10,20,30)
x = c(10,20,20,10,20,20,30,30)

#find matches:
inds <- lapply(y, function(z) which(z == x))

#all combinations of matches:
res <- do.call(expand.grid, inds)

#remove combinations with wrong order:
res <- res[apply(res, 1, function(z) all(order(z) == seq_along(y))),]
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1     1    2    7
# 3     1    3    7
# 5     1    5    7
# 6     4    5    7
# 7     1    6    7
# 8     4    6    7
# 9     1    2    8
#11     1    3    8
#13     1    5    8
#14     4    5    8
#15     1    6    8
#16     4    6    8

nrow(res)
#[1] 12
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what I wanted. Do you have a recommendation for much larger vectors? (~60.000 elements)

Comment: I'd probably implement it with `for` loops in Rcpp. I would then start with the last element in `y` and work backwards.